How to parse x-www-form-urlencoded POST requests with JSON body?
I'm new to Flask and trying to build a Flask app to receive POST requests coming from an API, then insert data into a database.  The POST requests come as-is from a 3rd party program, I cannot modify how they are sent.  Below is an example from one such request:
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 264
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Arma Reforger/1.1.0.42 (Headless; Windows)
{"token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","events":[{"name":"serveradmintools_conflict_base_captured","title":"Base André's Beacon captured by Soviet Army","data":{"faction":"Soviet Army","base":"André's Beacon"},"timestamp":1716526768}]}

I am using Postman to simulate these requests using the same HTTP headers, since I'm testing locally.  I have tried parsing these requests a number of different ways and cannot get the results I want.  The two closest solutions I have found are the following:
1.) First attempt using request.get_data() and unquote:
from flask import Flask, request
from urllib.parse import unquote

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def events():
    requestData = request.get_data()
    eventData = unquote(requestData) # works but replaces first colon with equals sign?
    return eventData

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

And the results I see in Postman look like this (notice how the first colon in the JSON string is replaced with an equals sign.  I can't figure out why this is happening for the life of me):
{"token"="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","events":[{"name":"serveradmintools_conflict_base_captured","title":"Base André's Beacon captured by Soviet Army","data":{"faction":"Soviet Army","base":"André's Beacon"},"timestamp":1716526768}]}

2.) Second attempt using request.form:
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def events():
    eventData = request.form
    return eventData

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

But the results in Postman look like this (notice the extra, escaped double-quotes, and some of the characters didn't display properly). I've been able to fix the character display issue, and I could using regex or string replace to remove the extra, escaped double-quotes, but why are they there in the first place and is there a better way to do this?):
{
  "{\"token\"": "\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"events\":[{\"name\":\"serveradmintools_conflict_base_captured\",\"title\":\"Base Andr\u00e9's Beacon captured by Soviet Army\",\"data\":{\"faction\":\"Soviet Army\",\"base\":\"Andr\u00e9's Beacon\"},\"timestamp\":1716526768}]}"
}


I just want to parse the submitted POST data as JSON so I can then insert it into a database.  How should I do this properly?  I have tried things like request.get_json(force=True) and json.loads() but it fails with errors about invalid JSON (even though running the JSON string through a validator says its valid).
Here are screenshots of the request headers and body in Postman:
POST Request Body in Postman
HTTP Request Headers in Postman
Any and all help is greatly appreciated! :)
Update: I can't figure out why the json isn't parsed correctly, but I've just added some extra code to check and replace the random equals sign with a colon, which fixes the string to be valid JSON.  Below is the code for my solution.  I still don't feel like this is the best way, but until I find a better solution...
from flask import Flask, request
from urllib.parse import unquote

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def events():
    requestData = unquote(request.get_data())
    eventData = requestData
    # check for equals sign in first 10 chars, replace it with colon:
    firstChars = eventData[:10]
    if '=' in firstChars:
        eventDataJson = eventData.replace('=',':')

    return eventDataJson


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


Those requests are not URL-form encoded. That looks like a JSON request with a wrong Content-Type header.

@deceze Thanks, but if it's JSON then why does json.loads() return invalid json errors?  Also, in the code of first attempt above, if I omit the unquote() and just have request.get_data(), it returns this: %7B%22token%22=%22xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%22%2C%22events%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22serveradmintools_conflict_base_captured%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Base%20Andr%C3%A9%27s%20Beacon%20captured%20by%20Soviet%20Army%22%2C%22data%22%3A%7B%22faction%22%3A%22Soviet%20Army%22%2C%22base%22%3A%22Andr%C3%A9%27s%20Beacon%22%7D%2C%22timestamp%22%3A1716526768%7D%5D%7D

Does this answer your question? Flask - How do I read the raw body in a POST request when the content type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

@BenchVue Thanks for the help, but I did see this post and tried this already.  I got an error about dict_keys() object is not subscriptable, I think it's because I'm using Python3 and according to another post, "In Python 3 dict.keys() returns an iterable but not indexable object".  I tried some other workarounds like next(iter(request.form.keys())) but no luck.

maybe you should show link to this API so we could test it. And maybe you should send this problem to authors of API because they something screw up

I think the best solution is to send information to authors of API and they should fix this mistake in API. But at this moment your last code seems the best solution.

you could do one modification - data may have more = in some other places so better replace "token"= with "token":

@furas Thanks for reply.  The API request is coming from dedicated server hosting a game called Arma Reforger, it's a mod for that game.  Heres a link to the mod: https://reforger.armaplatform.com/workshop/5AAAC70D754245DD, you can't view the code unless you download and unpack the .pak file in the mod. I'll reach out to the mod developer and ask them if they can change the Content-Type to JSON.  Good point about other equals signs, I will consider that.  It's possible equals signs could exist in the token itself or in the events data itself, so I need to make sure to account for that.
